# Spotlight and the locate command don't search *all* folders

Tags: macos, search, spotlight

There are several places in Mac OS X, that don't get indexed by spotlight or the terminal locate command.

Is there a way to change that?

How can I search in places like /private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`locate` should include system files (if you enable database creation -- it's turned off by default, at least in Snow Leopard -- with the command `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist`).

Spotlight does index system files, but normally leaves them out of the search results because most users want to search *their* files, not the OS internals.  If you want to see system files in the results, you have to enable them:

1. Start a Spotlight search by entering something in the search field in a Finder window toolbar.
2. Add an additional search criterion by clicking the "+" button on the right.
3. The new criterion selector will start saying something like `(Kind) is (Any)`.  Select "Other" from the attribute ("Kind") pop-up menu.
4. This'll open a dialog with a huge list of searchable attributes, with checkboxes to control whether they appear in the standard criterion pop-up.  Enable the "System Files" and "File invisible" attributes.
5. Now select "System Files" from the attribute pop-up, and "are included" from the next one.  If you want/need to, you can also add another search criterion to include/exclude invisible items (this doesn't seem to be necessary to search /private, even though it's invisible).
6. You should now see system files in the listed results.

Note that including these options in the pop-up menu is permanent, but actually selecting them has to be re-done for each search (i.e. next time you search, you only get to skip steps 3 and 4).

Comment: That's good to know!

Answer (score 1):

```
find /private -name *thethingimlookingfor*
```

It's not indexed but it will search :)

Comment: This works great if I already know that what I'm looking for is in /private. Otherwise could I perform a find directly under /? Do I need any special permissions for that?

Comment: Yes you can use that to search under / as well. You will need to use sudo to get access to most system folders though, plus it might take a while :)