# Search through all files when searching in Finder

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, search, finder, spotlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spotlight and the locate command don't search *all* folders](https://superuser.com/questions/195425/spotlight-and-the-locate-command-dont-search-all-folders)

Is there a way to search through all files from Finder? Currently it only searches "safe" files but I would like to include all hidden folders (`/usr`, `/etc`, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that's what you need:

- Open a new Spotlight search window with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.
- Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button
- In *Kind*, select *Other...* and enter "System". Select "System files" and click OK.

[image]

- Change "aren't included" to "are included"
- Enter your query, and voilà, there are your files from the system folders.

[image]